# Translate systemd unit instances

Tags: systemd

I have a service called `homie@.service` which is instanciated using a respective service ID.
This unit can be activated by `homie@.timer`, which is instanciated in the same fashion.

However I also want to be able to activate `homie@.service` via `homie@.path` which is instantiated using a POSIX path on the local system.

I have a script that translates the respective paths to the appropriate service IDs.

How can I invoke it in `homie@.path` so that `homie@.service` receives the service ID rather than the path?